# Add to dictionary in if loop

Tags: python, object

I have an if loop in which I am trying to;

(1) Create a dataframe from a filepath.

(2) Format this dataframe

(3) Add that dataframe to a dictionary that is a property of an instance of a class.

Here is my code defining the class and the method:

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self, name, filepathlist):
        self.name = name
        self.filepathlist = filepathlist

    def formatData(self):
        i = 0
        self.dataframeDict = {}
        if i < (len(self.filepathlist) - 1):
            DFRAW = pd.read_csv(self.filepathlist[i], header = 9) #Row 9 is the row that is not blank (all blank auto-skipped)
            DFRAW['DateTime'], DFRAW['dummycol1'] = DFRAW['    ;W;W;W;W'].str.split(';', 1).str
            DFRAW['Col1'], DFRAW['dummycol2'] = DFRAW['dummycol1'].str.split(';', 1).str
            DFRAW['Col2'], DFRAW['dummycol3'] = DFRAW['dummycol2'].str.split(';', 1).str
            DFRAW['Col3'], DFRAW['Col4'] = DFRAW['dummycol3'].str.split(';', 1).str
            DFRAW = DFRAW.drop(['    ;W;W;W;W', 'dummycol1', 'dummycol2', 'dummycol3'], axis = 1)

            dictIndex = self.filepathlist[i][39:44]

            self.dataframeDict.update({dictIndex: DFRAW})
            i = i + 1
```

Then I create an instance of the class and run the method:

```
filepathlist = ['filepath1','filepath2']
myINST = myClass('Mydataname', filepathlist)
myINST.formatData()
```

I then expect `myINST.dataframeDict` to have two dataframes as per the 2 input filepaths and thus 2 iterations of the if loop. However only 1 is present.

What is the error in my code or my approach?

Comment: There is no such thing as an "if loop", did you mean to use a `while` or `for` loop? `if` statements execute at most once. Perhaps `for i in range(len(self.filepathlist))`

Comment: You're probably looking to replace `if i < ... ` with `while i < ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to tell whether this will completely solve your problem, because no dummy data is provided. You will, however, get one step closer to your solution if you replace `if i < (len(self.filepathlist) - 1):` with `while i < (len(self.filepathlist) - 1):`.

You are currently just checking if `i=0` is smaller than `len(self.filepathlist)-1`. If so, then the if-block is executed *once*. What you are actually looking for is a loop that keeps on iterating, as long as `i` is smaller than `len(self.filepathlist)-1`. This is done with `while`-loops.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your condition to `for i in range(len(self.filepathlist)):`

(Also, remove the assignment of `i` as the `for` loop does it automatically. For the same reason, you should also remove the line which increments `i`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a `while` loop, change the `if` line to `while i < len(self.filepathlist):`.

Notice that there's no `-1`. This is because you're using `<` instead of `<=`. If you want to use `-1`, then you also need the `<=` as this will ensure the loop runs the correct number of times.